# Can't login after clean install

Tags: 16.04, server, login

I just did a clean install of Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS on VMware machine. During the instalation process I was asked to type username and password and I did. But, I can't login with that user after installation. I'm pretty sure that username and password are correct. I did reinstalled it twice and same problem happens.

I've tried `root`, `sageadmin` (created during installation), `admin`. None of them are correct, it gives me "Login incorrect" message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset password and try...

1. Reboot your computer
2. Hold Shift during boot to start GRUB menu
3. Highlight your image and press E to edit
4. Find the line starting with "linux" and append rw init=/bin/bash at the end of that line
5. Press Ctrl+X to boot.
6. Type in passwd username
7. Set your password.
8. Type in reboot. If that doesn't work, hit Ctrl+Alt+Del

Comment: Thx for help. Works fine

Comment: Doesn't work in 18.04

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 I had to remount the drive with write mode enabled by entering `mount -o remount,rw '/'` before trying to change the password